# How can I change a div background image depending on what results are being displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, filter

I have an app showing a list of venues as partials where each venue belongs to an area. The venues can be filtered by what area they are in. I would like the screen to be split down the centre, showing the venue partials down the left side and have a 'hand drawn' map on the right side. How can I change the image being displayed in the right hand side map div depending on what venues are being displayed?

I would like the default to be a zoomed out map showing all the areas but when all the venues being displayed have so same area_id number I would like the map image to change to a zoomed in detailed map of that area.

So a bit like this:

if all the venues being displayed area_id = 1 then display this area image
 
or if the area_id = 2 then display this area image
else display this other zoomed out image

I would eventually like for each venue to have its own icon on the map placed with  absolute positioning inside the map div.

I have about 2 months programming experience and maybe thinking this would need to be done in javascript or jquery (which I know nothing about) but not sure, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this with this bit of jQuery in the venue partial html.erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.left= "<%= venue.iconleftpx %>px";
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.top= "<%= venue.icontoppx %>px";
</script>
```

I added iconleftpx:integer and icontoppx:integer fields to the venue table which populate the top and left values for the absolute positioning called by the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the area codes as classes on your elements and set up background images in CSS for each class.

```
<div class="area_id_1"></div>
```

css:

```
.area_id_1 {
  background-image:url(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, Im a bit confused though, do you mean all the partials are elements?